# Run multiple MySQL queries in this node.js function

Tags: node.js, promise, node-mysql, node-async

I have this node.js function which returns a Promise after executing a single MySQL query.

```
function deletePoint(PointObj, door_id) {

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
        var connection = jonMySQL.getMySQL_connection();

        var mysql_query = '`DELETE FROM table1 WHERE user_id=? and door_id=?`';

        var mysql_query_placeholder_arr = [PointObj.user_id, door_id];

        connection.query(mysql_query, mysql_query_placeholder_arr, function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(rows);
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
    }
});
```

}
The above function works fine. However, what if I would like the function to finish running 2 MYSQL queries?

The second query would look something like this;

```
var mysql_query2 = '`DELETE FROM table2 WHERE user_id=? and door_id=?`';
var mysql_query2_placeholder_arr = [PointObj.user_id, door_id];
```

How do I integrate this second MySQL query into the function such that the Promise will return only after both queries have been executed?

EDIT: It would be preferable if the answer provided can handle up to several queries (say, up to 5) without callback hell. Can someone provide an answer using async module?

Comment: You can write second query in first's callback and return then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to create a generalized method to execute queries, you can modify it as per your requirement.

**Note:** running sequentially you have to manage the row that you are returning in `resolve(rows)`. In parallel all the rows gets produced in final successCallback `result` parameter as array of objects.

```
function deletePoint(PointObj, door_id){  
  var query = {
    text : '`DELETE FROM table1 WHERE user_id=? and door_id=?`',
    placeholder_arr : [PointObj.user_id, door_id],

  };
  var query2 = {
    text : '`DELETE FROM table2 WHERE user_id=? and door_id=?`',
    placeholder_arr : [PointObj.user_id, door_id],

  };

  //do this if you want to execute the queries sequentially 
  mySQLQuery(query).then(mySQLQuery(query2)).then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback);

  //do this if you want to execute the queries parallely
  var query_arr = [mySQLQuery(query),mySQLQuery(query2),...];                   
  Promise.all(query_arr).then(successCallback,errorCallback)


  function successCallback(result){
    console.log('done',result);
  }
  function errorCallback(err){
    console.log('Error while executing SQL Query',err);
  }

}


function mySQLQuery(query) {

var connection = jonMySQL.getMySQL_connection();
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
      connection.query(query.text, query.placeholder_arr, function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            } else {
                return resolve(rows);
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return reject(err);
    }
});
```

Besides, you can always use [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) module,

- `async.parallel` for parallel execution,
- `async.waterfall` for sequential execution with values passed from one function to other or
- `async.series` if no values need to be passed between sequential functions.

Comment: Nivesh, Verified to be correct answer. Made some edits to your code which has some syntax error. Please approve. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest, rather that creating connection every time you call mySQLQuery function, you should try implementing connection [pooling](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections). Check out how I structured the code while using PostgreSQL [myRepo](https://github.com/nivesh2/DaysNote/blob/master/server/functions/database/dbAccess.js).

Comment: May I ask what is the advantage and disadvantage, if any, of using connection pooling versus creating connection every time MySQLQuery function is called?

Comment: Connecting and disconnecting from a database is an expensive operation. Thus, connection pools are used to enhance the performance of executing commands on a database. In connection pooling, after a connection is created, it is placed in the pool and it is used again so that a new connection does not have to be established. If all the connections are being used, a new connection is made and is added to the pool. Connection pooling also cuts down on the amount of time a user must wait to establish a connection to the database. You get more about it by googling.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
function deletePoint(PointObj, door_id) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        try {
            var connection = jonMySQL.getMySQL_connection();

            var mysql_query = 'DELETE FROM table1 WHERE user_id = ? and door_id = ?';

            var mysql_query_placeholder_arr = [PointObj.user_id, door_id];

            connection.query(mysql_query, mysql_query_placeholder_arr, function(err, rows1, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                } else {
                    var mysql_query2 = 'DELETE FROM table2 WHERE user_id = ? and door_id = ?';
                    var mysql_query2_placeholder_arr = [PointObj.user_id, door_id];
                    connection.query(mysql_query, mysql_query_placeholder_arr, function(err, rows2, fields) {
                        if (err) {
                            return reject(err);
                        } else {
                            resolve({
                                rows1: rows1,
                                rows2: rows2
                            });
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}
```

---

**Suggestion**

It's not the better approach to writing multiple queries in a callback.

To resolve such type of case use [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) module with [parallel](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.parallel) or [waterfall](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.waterfall) methods based on scenario

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. There is a high possibility that this function would grow to cover several queries. I am afraid that the code can grow to become quite ugly if the function needs to handle, say, 5 queries.

Comment: I recommended to use `async` module which has better way to resolve such type of case  https://github.com/caolan/async